# Why does my HTML category menu move the right when expanding the subcategories?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, accordion

I'm using the jQueryUI accordion widget to provide the functionality I need. I'm not that familiar with IE tweaks so the solution escapes me.

If you visit my [test site](http://dss.com.bo:2525/), try to expand the categories using a modern browser such as Firefox, Opera or Chrome. It works as intended.

However when using **IE8**, the category tree moves to the left a bit, and there is even some bigger separation between the categories themselves.

What can I do to fix this bad behavior?

(*Note: Forget about IE6,7 support, it just has to work, not look pretty.* )

Comment: On a side note.  There's a clear bug in FF (prob. for all browsers).  Click the "CCTV" "+" icon.  That expands some categories such as "Cameras" and "DVR".  Now, click the "+" icon for any category, say "Cameras".  Your "CCTV" "-" icon gets reverted back to a "+" icon.  That may or may not be related to your IE 8 issue, but if that "+"/"-" icon is being reset, it's possible some CSS class tag is being re-introduced that's causing the IE issue.

Comment: Side note 2.  Your IE bug effects IE9 too.  This really looks like some kind of CSS issue.  Your list shifts over on the first click, so my above note isn't likely the culprit.

Comment: But so far this affects only IE. Any idea why? Or maybe you can suggest a cleaner way to achieve this same list functionality with different HTML and CSS? I'm open to any suggestions. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove width from categories class, tried in ie8 and problem disappear

Answer (score 1):

You have poorly formed HTML5 markup.  That might not be helping.  The number of list elements you have is real long so I'll just give a snippit.

```
<div class="widget-box">
    <h1>MENÚ PRODUCTOS</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="categories">
            <h3><img src="http://i.imgur.com/TThAk.gif" /><a href="/Productos/Categoria/66">CCTV</a><p class="subtext">Circuito cerrado de televisi&#243;n </p></h3>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <div class="categories">
                        <h3><img src="http://i.imgur.com/TThAk.gif" /><a href="/Productos/Categoria/74">Camaras</a><p class="subtext"></p></h3>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <div class="categories">
                                    <h3><a class="nochild" href="/Productos/Categoria/115">Camaras Infrarrojas</a><p class="subtext nochild"></p></h3>
                                    <div>
                                        <ul></ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="categories">
                                    <h3><a class="nochild" href="/Productos/Categoria/116">Profesional</a><p class="subtext nochild"></p></h3>
                                    <div>
                                        <ul></ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

On the 7th and 11th line above, you have UL tags but then proceed to use DIV tags.  UL tags can only have LI elements as a child per W3. http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/ul.html

I think your HTML could be closer to this:

```
<div class="widget-box">
    <h1>MENÚ PRODUCTOS</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
        <li>
            <h3><a href="#">CCTV <b>Circuito cerrado de televisi&#243;n</b></a></h3>
            <ul>
            <li>
                <h3><a href="#">Camaras</a></h3>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Camaras Infrarrojas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profesional</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Though, there's probably better semantic use of tags possible than what I've got here.

You can then add a little padding to the left of your H3 > a tag and use the +/- gif as a background image that can be swapped with a CSS class.  That will make the swap real straight forward in jQuery to simply toggle the clicked anchor class.  That will help solve the previous bug I mentioned.

I hope that helps a little as Yucel seems to have a solution for the other issue, but there might be more going on with the HTML issues.

Cheers!